# Karma Start vs grunt task call

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I am trying to do karma code coverage using `karma-coverage`. When calling `karma start` code coverage is generated successfully. But when the same is triggered via `grunt` the coverage results are not generated properly.

Could some provide some insight on this.? Thanks.